# isplitVector and foreach indexing issue

Tags: r, foreach, python-itertools, parallel-foreach

I am a beginner in parallel computing with R. I recently started using the foreach and parallel computing using the doParallel package. I have a an issue when i am trying to index a list after splitting a iterator into chunks.

```
library(itertools)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
    n=10000
    iter = 1:n
    cores = detectCores() -1
    c = makeCluster(cores)
    clusterExport(c,c("mod_function","test_list","cores")
    registerDoParallel(c)
    output <- foreach(i = isplitVector(iter,chunks = cores)) %dopar%
    {
    mod_function(test_list[[i]]
    }
    stopCluster(c)
```

I get the error

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "recursive indexing failed at level 3
```

I do not get the error when I do not split the iteration vector into chunks. I am not sure what exactly does the isplitVector returns and how I go about indexing the list. This works for me

```
n=10000
iter = 1:n
cores = detectCores() -1
c = makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(c)
output <- foreach(i = (1:n) %dopar%
    {
    mod_function(test_list[[i]]
    }
stopCluster(c)
```

Since I have a lot of iterations, I thought the best way to speed up my foreach was to chunk the iterations to the cluster. Any help in this direction would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Imo, I have added the packages I have used and the variable I exported.

Answer (score 2):

The `isplitVector` function returns an iterator that returns sub-vectors (or sub-lists) of its first argument. You're getting an error because you're using `[[` to index into `test_list` with a vector. You might be able to use `[` instead, but that would fail if `mod_function` doesn't accept list arguments.

Here's one way to break up your example into `cores` tasks that works even if `mod_function` doesn't accept list arguments:

```
output <- 
  foreach(s=isplitVector(test_list, chunks=cores), .combine='c') %dopar% {
    lapply(s, mod_function)
  }
```

Note that it uses `c` to combine the lists returned by `lapply` into a single list.